# How to keep previous object active using ngFor in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the json data as below.

```
 [
{
    "route":"vehicle",
    "next-route":"driver",
    "isActive":false
},
{
    "title":"Driver",
    "route":"driver",
    "next-route":"driver-details",
    "isActive":false
},
{
    "title":"Driver",
    "route":"driver-details",
    "next-route":"quote",
    "isActive":true
},
{
    "title":"Quote",
    "route":"quote",
    "next-route":"",
    "isActive":false
}
 ]
```

I am trying to loop through each object and if title is same ,
Iam displaying only the first object in the menubar. Based on the isActive field (which gets updated based on route) I am applying the active class to the object.

The following are the 3 titles displayed in the menubar and I want to keep the driver active for both the driver objects.

- Vehicle
- Driver
- Quote

I am comparing the current title with previous title and if both matches , i am skipping that object using ngIf condition

```
  <ul>
    <ng-container let menu of menuArray; let i=index>
      <!-- for 0 index there is no title , so ignore -->
      <ng-container *ngIf=" menu && menu.title && menuArray[i-1].title !== menuArray[i].title">
        <li [ngClass]="{active: menu.isActive}">
          <div>{{menu.title}}</div>
        </li>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </ul>
```

How to keep the first driver object active when the current index is in second driver object (The second driver object will be skipped in the ngIf condition and not displayed in menubar)

Comment: That's a lot of logic, probably too much for the view. Transform your data and apply your logic in the component. Then, simply display the transformed data in the view. The view is not the place to implement business logic like that.

Comment: terrible hack is extending conditon {active: menu.isActive || (menuArray[i-1].title === menuArray[i].title) && menuArray[i-1].isActive } but I can't recomment it. @JeremyThille is right. Transform it in component and provide proper items to ngFor. You live will be much easier.

Comment: @JeremyThille I have achieved the same by writing my own logic in ts file. I have other functionality for displaying icons. There are 3 different icons , 1 for Active , visited and notVisited titles. I am calling a function by passing title to check the current status and displaying icons accordingly. I am observing flickering in the icons when the route changes. So , wanted to see if there is any better solution to do it in view. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I think you just want to place the first active one, so compare if the last one was active

```
<ng-container *ngIf=" menu && menu.title && (menuArray[i-1].title !== menuArray[i].title || !menuArray[i-1].isActive)">
```

**EDIT**

Just noticed this is very much the same as @farincz recommendation in the comments.